# Non-destructively handling Django user messages

Tags: django

I'm displaying user messages through templates using RequestContext in Django, which gives access to user messages through {{messages}} template variable - that's convenient.

I'd like user **him/herself** delete the messages - is there a way to do it in Django without rewriting much code? Unfortunately Django automatically deletes messages at each request - not very useful in this case.

Django doc says:

```
"Note that RequestContext calls get_and_delete_messages() behind the scenes"
```

Would be perfect if there were a way to simply turn off the automatic deletion of messages!

---

**NOTE:** Unfortunately solution below makes **admin interface unusable**. I don't know how to get around this, really annoying.

**EDIT - found a solution** - use custom auth context processor that calls user.message_set.all() as Alex Martelli suggested. There's no need to change the application code at all with this solution. (context processor is a component in django that injects variables into templates.)

create file myapp/context_processors.py

and replace in settings.py in **`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`** tuple
     **`django.core.context_processors.auth`** with **`myapp.context_processors.auth_processor`**

put into myapp/context_processors.py:

```
def auth_processor(request):
    """
    this function is mostly copy-pasted from django.core.context_processors.auth
    it does everything the same way except keeps the messages
    """
    messages = None
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            messages = user.message_set.all()
    else:
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        user = AnonymousUser()
    from django.core.context_processors import PermWrapper
    return {
        'user': user,
        'messages': messages,
        'perms': PermWrapper(user),
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to retain message set. It is meant for displaying the message to user; and once that is done, it will be deleted.

Comment: @becomingGuru I want to make the sure user acknowledges important messages. one tells them that they have to validate email before their input can be published. They can still click the little cross box to dismiss the message permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds like a strange approach, but you could copy into your own list

```
request.user.message_set.all()
```

before instantiating RequestContext, and later put them back in..

Comment: Alex, thanks. I think I found a good solution - posted it as update in my question.